# SqlDataAdapter Insert Database not working C# winform

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server database and show on DatagridView from a C# Winforms.

I click on the Insert button no error shows, but no data is being Insert into the database and Datagridview becomes blank.

I re-debug that can see data update in datagridview, but the database is not on Visual Studio Server Explorer DataBase(picture1).

On the other hand.I set breakpoint when click Insert Button,that jump over line 42~46.Directly to line 50.ex(picture2).

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y23Mk.jpg)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNXjD.jpg)

**Edit**：
The question now is when I click insert button,datagridview have update new data.But database no insert new data.Database only two data.

**Edit2**
I changed connection string AttachDbFilename.
`AttachDbFilename=C:\Vis\NO4\WindowsFormsApplication1\App_Dat‌​a\Database1.mdf;`
The value can insert database.

Here is the connection string:

```
<add name="con1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here is the Form_load and load_grid function

```
SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       load_grid();
    }
    public void load_grid()
    {
        dt.Clear();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM profile";
            con.Open();
            da1.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            da1.Fill(ds);
            da1.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Insert Button

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ac = textBox1.Text;
        string bd = textBox2.Text;
        string sex = textBox2.Text;
        string sql = "INSERT INTO profile(ac,bd,sex)VALUES('" + ac + "','" + bd + "','" + sex + "')";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.Update(dt);
            MessageBox.Show("INsert success...!!");
            load_grid();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here is the design of the Costumer table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[profile] (
[Id]  INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ac]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[bd]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[sex] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

Not sure where the issue is here.

Comment: Where have you initialized connection? I do not see providing connection string?

Comment: sorry! I miss it. Has been added.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Picture2 shows an exception that connection is already open so, try following before opening a connection. You are calling `load_grid();` before closing connection.
I have update all code, use it as explained below:

Edit- Second Revision:

```
public void load_grid()
    {
        dt.Clear();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM profile";
            con.Open();
            da1.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            da1.Fill(ds);
            da1.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Close();
        }
    }


 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ac = textBox1.Text;
            string bd = textBox2.Text;
            string sex = textBox2.Text;
            string sql = "INSERT INTO profile(ac,bd,sex)VALUES('" + ac + "','" + bd + "','" + sex + "')";
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                da.Update(dt);
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("INsert success...!!");
                load_grid();               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Very thank you.Datagridview has been updated after I click insert button.
But the profile table will not insert, only test and test1.

Comment: And I have quertion.Why con is not closed, in the first call load grid () function.

Comment: if any exception occur in first or second query ever, it will never be able to close connection until closing application. your code is not clean, I see many issues. I have updated my answer check and let me know if issue still persists.

Comment: did you mean that only two values are inserted instead of 3? it might be because you are taking textBox2 text for two fields? bd and sex columns?

Comment: Just noticed you are calling  load_grid(); after da.Update(dt); which means you connection is not yet closed.   Move the   con.Close(); before load_grid()

Comment: con.close I got it.
The picture1 mean (http://imgur.com/xI5GKjw) .When I click insert button,datagridview have show new data.But database no insert 'test3' data.

Comment: Is issue fixed?

Comment: No.The question now is when I click insert button,datagridview have update new data.But database no insert  new data.

Comment: Database only two data .No matter how I add no update from insert button

Comment: Hi @Munawar.Today I change connection string `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;`became
`AttachDbFilename=C:\Vis\NO4\WindowsFormsApplication1\App_Data\Database1.mdf;`

Comment: The value can insert database.It's seem to database absolute path and relative path issue.